# magento: remove page layouts

Tags: magento

In magento the following page layouts are defined by default: `empty`, `one_column`, `two_columns_left`, `two_columns_right` and `three_columns`.

I would like to remove `two_columns_left`, `two_columns_right` for my layout, since the user can choose it in CMS and product design section, but it doesn't work.

How do I change an XML configuration file to accomplish this?

I found that I can remove it from the `app/core/community/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml`, but I would like to do this without change any core source, to be updateable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the root layouts are parsed from config XML, and due to the way in which config XML is merged together, your simplest option (as you've surmised) is to edit `app/core/community/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml`.

If you are *really* concerned with not editing core files - always a legitimate & fun endeavor - you could create a module that can handle remove_layout directives, which you could add in your module's config under the same xpath. The class you would be rewriting is `Mage_Page_Model_Config` - see the `_appendPageLayouts()` and `getPageLayouts()` methods.

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled across this question looking for something similar and want to share my implementation. Maybe it is helpful for someone out there.

The following will remove the empty, 2_columns_right and 3_columns layouts from the list of available templates. Just change the `remove_layouts` directive in the `config.xml` below to remove whatever you want to remove.

I created a module (in fact the very first module I've ever built for magento) and placed the following in the file `app/etc/modules/Labor_Templates.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * This module changes the available templates. Only "1 column" and
 * "2 column-left" will be available.
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Labor_Templates>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Labor_Templates>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, we need a `config.xml` found in `/app/code/local/Labor/Templates/etc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Overrides the config to only allow "1 column" and "2 column left" layouts.
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Labor_Templates>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Labor_Templates>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <template>
                <class>Labor_Templates_Model</class>
            </template>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Labor_Templates_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </models>
        <page>
            <remove_layouts>
                <layouts>empty,two_columns_right,three_columns</layouts>
            </remove_layouts>
        </page>   
    </global>
</config>
```

Notice, that I've added the `remove_layouts` directive. Finally we write our own `Labor_Templates_Model_Config` class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Overrides the Overrides the core module Mage_Page_Model_Config in order to
 * remove unused template layouts. This is done by handling remove_layout
 * directives.
 */
class Labor_Templates_Model_Config extends Mage_Page_Model_Config {

    const XML_PATH_PAGE_REMOVE_LAYOUTS = 'global/page/remove_layouts';

    /**
     * Initialize page layouts list
     *
     * @return Labor_Templates_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _initPageLayouts()
    {
        parent::_initPageLayouts();
        return $this->_removePageLayouts(self::XML_PATH_PAGE_REMOVE_LAYOUTS);
    }

    /**
     * Removes page layouts found in the remove_layouts XML directive
     * 
     * @return Labor_Templates_Model_Config 
     */
    protected function _removePageLayouts($xmlPath)
    {
        if (!Mage::getConfig()->getNode($xmlPath) || !is_array($this->_pageLayouts)) {
            return $this;
        }
        foreach (explode(',', (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode($xmlPath)->children()->layouts) as $toRemove) {
            unset($this->_pageLayouts[$toRemove]);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Works and tested with Magento 1.7.0.