# Magento: layouts not appearing in CMS page dropdown

Tags: magento

I just installed the Bootstrap template into my Magento install. I uploaded the files, went to System > Design and added the design change. The frontend of my site now displays the theme, but when I go to CMS > Pages and select a page, the Layout dropdown still shows the default/default layouts, not the ones as defined in app/design/frontend/bootstrap/default/layout/page.xml

Any ideas why they are not appearing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because Page.xml doesn't define the CMS page layouts for that drop down menu.  You can find more information on it here;

[magento: remove page layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226978/magento-remove-page-layouts)

This Inchoo post is a good way to add your own CMS page layout types via a super simple module (one of the answers in the above link takes a similar approach);

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/

Comment: Thanks! I saw some direction similar to that, but I'm just confused by the seeming redundancy in the xml files. The page.xml file that comes with Bootstrap has all of the page layouts defined within ( http://pastebin.com/N4UUZDg7 ) – but I still need to add them to the local config.xml anyway? If it's not too much to ask, could you please explain to me the difference between / purpose of these files in relation to each other?

Comment: I'll be honest - I don't have a clue what that section of code in page.xml is for, although I'm sure someone here will.  One of the many things I just leave alone with Magento :)  I do know it's nothing specific to Bootstrap, the base/default/layout/page.xml file contains that exact same section of code.

Comment: Thanks McNab. Finally (hopefully), I have one more issue. I followed the instructions on inchoo. 
added: app/code/local/Lokai/LokaiLayouts/etc/config.xml
and added what I think it proper xml
added: app/etc/modules/Lokai_LokaiLayouts.xml
with instructions to use local codepool
added home.phtml to app/design/frontend/lokai/default/template/page/
applied the Home layout to the homepage via CMS>Home>Design>Layout dropdown
but now when i go to the homepage its just a blank white page :(

Comment: Blank white page equals PHP error, the legendary white screen of death.  I'm assuming you don't have developer mode turned on?  http://alanstorm.com/magento_exception_handling_developer_mode  Try just putting in some html to see if your page module is working at least, then debug the template file itself.

Comment: very frustrating - can't even get php errors to display. i have this in my index.php file: Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); but still wsod. i also have logging enabled but nothing is logged.

Comment: Hmm, a few suggestions here -> stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen